# What's a basic way of obtaining a list of friends of a certain user on Facebook? (Just their IDs)

Tags: php, api, facebook

I just want to access a full list of a user's facebook friends via the API, using PHP

Surely I won't need to authenticate this with the user, as this is public information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You in fact do have to authenticate. Even though many people have their friends lists as public using the web interface, Facebook still requires an access_token to call the friends api. The call using the Graph API is:

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/friends?fields=id&access_token=...

Answer (score -2):

This is explained pretty well here, sorry I don't have time to go into detail:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api